# How do I convert a big hexadecimal file to a binary file?

Tags: java, android

I Have a text file with the size of 2.4MB

How can I convert it into java?

I use this code but it is not valid:

This initializes the File:

```
File file = new File("E:/Binary.txt");

//   if file doesnt exists, then create it
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

try {
    String sCurrentLine;
    String bits ="";
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:/base1.txt"));
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        bits = hexToBin(sCurrentLine);
    }

    bw.write(bits);
    bw.close();
    System.out.println("done....");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null)br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This Methods to convert:

```
static String hexToBin(String s) {
    return new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2);
}
```

Comment: what's exactly your problem?

Comment: this way not work when i try it no thing happen

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happened"?  Did it create a file, or not?  Was the file empty or not?  When you opened the file as a text file using a text editor, did it consist of "1" characters and "0" characters?  Was that what you expected?

Comment: I don't think that your hex decoder works as expected. Use `Hex.decodeHex` from [apache commons-codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you mean by a hex file, any file can be read as a binary one and here is an example on how to read & write a binary file:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class BinaryFiles {

  public static void main(String... aArgs) throws IOException{
    BinaryFiles binary = new BinaryFiles();
    byte[] bytes = binary.readBinaryFile(FILE_NAME);
    log("size of file read in:" + bytes.length);
    binary.writeBinaryFile(bytes, OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
  }

  final static String FILE_NAME = "***srcPath***";
  final static String OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "***destPath***";

  byte[] readBinaryFile(String aFileName) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(aFileName);
    return Files.readAllBytes(path);
  }

  void writeBinaryFile(byte[] aBytes, String aFileName) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(aFileName);
    Files.write(path, aBytes); //creates, overwrites
  }

  private static void log(Object aMsg){
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(aMsg));
  }

}
```

If you want to convert hex to binary use this:

```
String hexToBinary(String hex) {
int intVal = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
String binaryVal = Integer.toBinaryString(intVal);
return binaryVal;
}
```

You could use the above example to make a combination of converting HEX to binary then writing it.

Comment: Thanks....I mean I have Hex File and size of file is 2.4MB when i convert to binary it doesn't work the IDE not display any result and generate empty file cause The file is big